# Limit access to Google Endpoint URL

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, openapi

I am trying to build a service to service API call. I am using Google Endpoints with open API.

My problem is that after adding "securityDefinitions:" I'm still able to access the endpoint without authentication. (Able to access it from anywhere)

How do I make sure that only Compute Engine with a particular Service Account can access the REST API.

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: "A simple Google Cloud Endpoints API example."
  title: "Endpoints Example"
  version: "1.0.0"
host: "echo-api.endpoints.projectid.cloud.goog"
x-google-endpoints:
  - name: "echo-api.endpoints.projectid.cloud.goog"
    target: "SOME IP"
# [END swagger]
basePath: "/"
consumes:
- "application/json"
produces:
- "application/json"
schemes:
- "http"
paths:
  "/list":
    get:
      description: "list"
      operationId: "Project.get"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "lists"
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Project"
      parameters:
      - description: "Project Name"
        in: body
        name: project_id
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: "#/definitions/Res"
      security:
      - google_jwt_client-1: []

definitions:
  Res:
    properties:
      apierrmsg:
        type: "string"
      apiresults:
        type: "Array"

definitions:
  Project:
    properties:
      project_id:
        type: "string"


securityDefinitions:
  google_jwt_client-1:
    authorizationUrl: ""
    flow: "implicit"
    type: "oauth2"
    x-google-issuer: "some@projectid.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/some@projectid.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
```

Comment: I have reproduced your post, getting the example from [this repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/endpoints/getting-started) and following [these docs](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine#before-you-begin). Of course, I have used your settings in the `openapi-appengine.yaml`. And it works for me... other than a service account accessing the Endpoint, I receive `code: 16, message: JWT validation failed: Missing or invalid credentials`

Comment: Can you try reproducing using those examples and try figuring out what are the salient differences? One difference I noticed is `schemes: -"http"` versus `schemes: -"https"`, but I am not sure of the impact.